# Wordpress permalink issue on AWS

Tags: permalinks

I have a weird issue with my permalinks in wordpress hosted on AWS.

In my browser it shows a nice permalink for the first post of: http://civicasoft.com/granicus-acquisition/ (can be reached by going to site and hitting news tab and the story on there)

But when I copy and paste the url from my browser it gives me this ugly one: http://civicasoft.com/%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BC%EF%BF%BCgranicus-acquisition/

Any ideas what is going on? Everything looks fine from the admin.. If I type in the nice looking url it says page not found.. I have to paste in the ugly one.

I am at my wits end. I have never had these issues with a wordpress install before.

```
######BEGIN SwiftSecurity######

######END SwiftSecurity######

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Unicode and probably not the fault of WordPress or AWS. Read more at : https://superuser.com/questions/480692/copying-unicode-symbols-from-firefox-address-bar-as-is .
Top answer from there:

> Try setting
>    http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.standard-url.escape-utf8 via
>   about:config http://kb.mozillazine.org/About%3aconfig
>
> Possible values and their effects:
>
> true - Escape UTF-8 URLs. (Default)false - Do not escape UTF-8 URLs.

That's a firefox solution. You didn't mention which browser you're using.